# Appium 'Failed to connect to the server. Please check that it is running' using Inspector

Tags: python, appium, inspector

What must be done to use Aappium's inspector?

The screenshot and logs are attached

1. my appium server is set to start an app (with path checked)
2. the AVD emulator is launched
3. the tests script is launched, with the app successfully loading on the emulator
4. when clicking on the 'inspector' button, the above error occurs

[image: Error displayed]

> Launching Appium server with command: C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node.exe lib\server\main.js --address 127.0.0.1 --port 4723 --app C:\test\TimeWorksMobile.apk --platform-name Android --platform-version 23 --automation-name Appium --log-no-color
>   info: Welcome to Appium v1.4.16 (REV ae6877eff263066b26328d457bd285c0cc62430d)
>   info: Appium REST http interface listener started on 127.0.0.1:4723
>   info: [debug] Non-default server args: {"app":"C:\test\TimeWorksMobile.apk","address":"127.0.0.1","logNoColors":true,"platformName":"Android","platformVersion":"23","automationName":"Appium"}
>   info: Console LogLevel: debug
>   info: --> POST /wd/hub/session {"requiredCapabilities":{},"desiredCapabilities":{"platformVersion":"5.1","app":"C:\test\TimeWorksMobile.apk","deviceName":"Android Emulator","platformName":"Android"}}
>   info: Client User-Agent string: Python-urllib/3.5
>   info: [debug] No appActivity desired capability or server param. Parsing from apk.
>   info: [debug] No appPackage desired capability or server param. Parsing from apk.
>   info: [debug] Using local app from desired caps: C:\test\TimeWorksMobile.apk
>   info: [debug] Creating new appium session 2c9eecab-c67b-45e0-b97f-0faa98dfd000
>   info: Starting android appium
>   info: [debug] Getting Java version
>   info: Java version is: 1.8.0_101
>   info: [debug] Checking whether adb is present
>   info: [debug] Using adb from C:\Users\mwebster\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe
>   info: [debug] Parsing package and activity from app manifest
>   info: [debug] Checking whether aapt is present
>   info: [debug] Using aapt from C:\Users\mwebster\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\24.0.2\aapt.exe
>   info: [debug] Extracting package and launch activity from manifest.
>   info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Users\mwebster\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\24.0.2\aapt.exe dump badging C:\test\TimeWorksMobile.apk
>   info: [debug] badging package: com.SwipeClock.SCeConnect
>   info: [debug] badging act: com.SwipeClock.SCeConnect.MainActivity
>   info: [debug] Parsed package and activity are: com.SwipeClock.SCeConnect/com.SwipeClock.SCeConnect.MainActivity
>   info: [debug] Using fast reset? true
>   info: [debug] Preparing device for session
>   info: [debug] Checking whether app is actually present
>   info: Retrieving device
>   info: [debug] Trying to find a connected android device
>   info: [debug] Getting connected devices...
>   info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Users\mwebster\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe devices
>   info: [debug] 1 device(s) connected
>   info: Found device emulator-5554
>   info: [debug] Setting device id to emulator-5554
>   info: [debug] Waiting for device to be ready and to respond to shell commands (timeout = 5)
>   info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Users\mwebster\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s emulator-5554 wait-for-device
>   info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Users\mwebster\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s emulator-5554 shell "echo 'ready'"
>   info: [debug] Starting logcat capture
>   info: [debug] Getting device API level
>   info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Users\mwebster\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s emulator-5554 shell "getprop ro.build.version.sdk"
>   info: [debug] Device is at API Level 23
>   info: Device API level is: 23
>   info: [debug] Extracting strings for language: default
>   info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Users\mwebster\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s emulator-5554 shell "getprop persist.sys.language"
>   info: [debug] Current device persist.sys.language: 
>   info: [debug] java -jar "C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-adb\jars\appium_apk_tools.jar" "stringsFromApk" "C:\test\TimeWorksMobile.apk" "C:\Users\mwebster\AppData\Local\Temp\com.SwipeClock.SCeConnect" 
>   info: [debug] Reading strings from converted strings.json
>   info: [debug] Setting language to default
>   info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Users\mwebster\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s emulator-5554 push "C:\Users\mwebster\AppData\Local\Temp\com.SwipeClock.SCeConnect\strings.json" /data/local/tmp
>   info: [debug] Checking whether aapt is present
>   info: [debug] Using aapt from C:\Users\mwebster\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\24.0.2\aapt.exe
>   info: [debug] Retrieving process from manifest.
>   info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Users\mwebster\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\24.0.2\aapt.exe dump xmltree C:\test\TimeWorksMobile.apk AndroidManifest.xml
>   info: [debug] Set app process to: com.SwipeClock.SCeConnect
>   info: [debug] Not uninstalling app since server not started with --full-reset
>   info: [debug] Checking app cert for C:\test\TimeWorksMobile.apk.
>   info: [debug] executing cmd: java -jar "C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-adb\jars\verify.jar" C:\test\TimeWorksMobile.apk
>   info: [debug] App already signed.
>   info: [debug] Zip-aligning C:\test\TimeWorksMobile.apk
>   info: [debug] Checking whether zipalign is present
>   info: [debug] Using zipalign from C:\Users\mwebster\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\24.0.2\zipalign.exe
>   info: [debug] Zip-aligning apk.
>   info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Users\mwebster\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\24.0.2\zipalign.exe -f 4 C:\test\TimeWorksMobile.apk C:\Users\mwebster\AppData\Local\Temp\116910-12700-dn10cl\appium.tmp
>   info: [debug] MD5 for app is 49680e5f3c45e35b7ae704bcc2859d86
>   info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Users\mwebster\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s emulator-5554 shell "ls /data/local/tmp/49680e5f3c45e35b7ae704bcc2859d86.apk"
>   info: [debug] Getting install status for com.SwipeClock.SCeConnect
>   info: [debug] Getting device API level
>   info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Users\mwebster\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s emulator-5554 shell "getprop ro.build.version.sdk"
>   info: [debug] Device is at API Level 23
>   info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Users\mwebster\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s emulator-5554 shell "pm list packages -3 com.SwipeClock.SCeConnect"
>   info: [debug] App is installed
>   info: App is already installed, resetting app
>   info: [debug] Running fast reset (stop and clear)
>   info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Users\mwebster\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s emulator-5554 shell "am force-stop com.SwipeClock.SCeConnect"
>   info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Users\mwebster\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s emulator-5554 shell "pm clear com.SwipeClock.SCeConnect"
>   info: [debug] Forwarding system:4724 to device:4724
>   info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Users\mwebster\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s emulator-5554 forward tcp:4724 tcp:4724
>   info: [debug] Pushing appium bootstrap to device...
>   info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Users\mwebster\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s emulator-5554 push "C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\build\android_bootstrap\AppiumBootstrap.jar" /data/local/tmp/
>   info: [debug] Pushing settings apk to device...
>   info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Users\mwebster\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s emulator-5554 install "C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\build\settings_apk\settings_apk-debug.apk"
>   info: [debug] Pushing unlock helper app to device...
>   info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Users\mwebster\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s emulator-5554 install "C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\build\unlock_apk\unlock_apk-debug.apk"
>   info: Starting App
>   info: [debug] Attempting to kill all 'uiautomator' processes
>   info: [debug] Getting all processes with 'uiautomator'
>   info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Users\mwebster\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s emulator-5554 shell "ps 'uiautomator'"
>   info: [debug] No matching processes found
>   info: [debug] Running bootstrap
>   info: [debug] spawning: C:\Users\mwebster\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s emulator-5554 shell uiautomator runtest AppiumBootstrap.jar -c io.appium.android.bootstrap.Bootstrap -e pkg com.SwipeClock.SCeConnect -e disableAndroidWatchers false
>   info: [debug] [UIAUTOMATOR STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: numtests=1
>   info: [debug] [UIAUTOMATOR STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: stream=
>   info: [debug] [UIAUTOMATOR STDOUT] io.appium.android.bootstrap.Bootstrap:
>   info: [debug] [UIAUTOMATOR STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: id=UiAutomatorTestRunner
>   info: [debug] [UIAUTOMATOR STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: test=testRunServer
>   info: [debug] [UIAUTOMATOR STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: class=io.appium.android.bootstrap.Bootstrap
>   info: [debug] [UIAUTOMATOR STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: current=1
>   info: [debug] [UIAUTOMATOR STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS_CODE: 1
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Socket opened on port 4724
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Appium Socket Server Ready
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Loading json...
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] json loading complete.
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Registered crash watchers.
>   info: [debug] Waking up device if it's not alive
>   info: [debug] Pushing command to appium work queue: ["wake",{}]
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Client connected
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got data from client: {"cmd":"action","action":"wake","params":{}}
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got command of type ACTION
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got command action: wake
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Returning result: {"status":0,"value":true}
>   info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Users\mwebster\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s emulator-5554 shell "dumpsys window"
>   info: [debug] Screen already unlocked, continuing.
>   info: [debug] Pushing command to appium work queue: ["getDataDir",{}]
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got data from client: {"cmd":"action","action":"getDataDir","params":{}}
>   info: [debug] dataDir set to: /data
>   info: [debug] Pushing command to appium work queue: ["compressedLayoutHierarchy",{"compressLayout":false}]
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got command of type ACTION
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got command action: getDataDir
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Returning result: {"status":0,"value":"/data"}
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got data from client: {"cmd":"action","action":"compressedLayoutHierarchy","params":{"compressLayout":false}}
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got command of type ACTION
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got command action: compressedLayoutHierarchy
>   info: [debug] Getting device API level
>   info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Users\mwebster\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s emulator-5554 shell "getprop ro.build.version.sdk"
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Returning result: {"status":0,"value":false}
>   info: [debug] Device is at API Level 23
>   info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Users\mwebster\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s emulator-5554 shell "am start -S -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER -f 0x10200000 -n com.SwipeClock.SCeConnect/com.SwipeClock.SCeConnect.MainActivity"
>   info: [debug] Waiting for pkg "com.SwipeClock.SCeConnect" and activity "com.SwipeClock.SCeConnect.MainActivity" to be focused
>   info: [debug] Getting focused package and activity
>   info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Users\mwebster\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s emulator-5554 shell "dumpsys window windows"
>   info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Users\mwebster\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s emulator-5554 shell "getprop ro.build.version.release"
>   info: [debug] Device is at release version 6.0
>   info: [debug] Device launched! Ready for commands
>   info: [debug] Setting command timeout to the default of 60 secs
>   info: [debug] Appium session started with sessionId 2c9eecab-c67b-45e0-b97f-0faa98dfd000
>   info: <-- POST /wd/hub/session 303 4044.963 ms - 74 
>   info: --> GET /wd/hub/session/2c9eecab-c67b-45e0-b97f-0faa98dfd000 {}
>   info: [debug] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":{"platform":"LINUX","browserName":"Android","platformVersion":"6.0","webStorageEnabled":false,"takesScreenshot":true,"javascriptEnabled":true,"databaseEnabled":false,"networkConnectionEnabled":true,"locationContextEnabled":false,"warnings":{},"desired":{"platformVersion":"5.1","app":"C:\test\TimeWorksMobile.apk","deviceName":"Android Emulator","platformName":"Android"},"app":"C:\test\TimeWorksMobile.apk","deviceName":"emulator-5554","platformName":"Android"},"sessionId":"2c9eecab-c67b-45e0-b97f-0faa98dfd000"}
>   info: <-- GET /wd/hub/session/2c9eecab-c67b-45e0-b97f-0faa98dfd000 200 3.418 ms - 538 {"status":0,"value":{"platform":"LINUX","browserName":"Android","platformVersion":"6.0","webStorageEnabled":false,"takesScreenshot":true,"javascriptEnabled":true,"databaseEnabled":false,"networkConnectionEnabled":true,"locationContextEnabled":false,"warnings":{},"desired":{"platformVersion":"5.1","app":"C:\test\TimeWorksMobile.apk","deviceName":"Android Emulator","platformName":"Android"},"app":"C:\test\TimeWorksMobile.apk","deviceName":"emulator-5554","platformName":"Android"},"sessionId":"2c9eecab-c67b-45e0-b97f-0faa98dfd000"}
>   {"platform":"LINUX","browserName":"Android","platformVersion":"6.0","webStorageEnabled":false,"takesScreenshot":true,"javascriptEnabled":true,"databaseEnabled":false,"networkConnectionEnabled":true,"locationContextEnabled":false,"warnings":{},"desired":{"platformVersion":"5.1","app":"C:\test\TimeWorksMobile.apk","deviceName":"Android Emulator","platformName":"Android"},"app":"C:\test\TimeWorksMobile.apk","deviceName":"emulator-5554","platformName":"Android"},"sessionId":"2c9eecab-c67b-45e0-b97f-0faa98dfd000"}
>   info: --> POST /wd/hub/session {"desiredCapabilities":{"app":"C:\test\TimeWorksMobile.apk","platformName":"Android"}}
>   info: Client User-Agent string: undefined
>   error: Failed to start an Appium session, err was: Error: Requested a new session but one was in progress
>   info: [debug] Error: Requested a new session but one was in progress
>       at [object Object].Appium.start (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\lib\appium.js:139:15)
>       at exports.createSession (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\lib\server\controller.js:188:16)
>       at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:82:5)
>       at next (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:110:13)
>       at Route.dispatch (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:91:3)
>       at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:82:5)
>       at C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:267:22
>       at Function.proto.process_params (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:321:12)
>       at next (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:261:10)
>       at next (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:100:14)
>       at next (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:104:14)
>       at next (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:104:14)
>       at next (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:104:14)
>       at next (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:104:14)
>       at next (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:104:14)
>       at next (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:104:14)
>       at next (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:104:14)
>       at next (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:104:14)
>       at next (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:104:14)
>       at next (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:104:14)
>       at C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\lib\server\controller.js:39:7
>       at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:82:5)
>       at next (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:110:13)
>       at next (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:104:14)
>       at next (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:104:14)
>       at next (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:104:14)
>       at next (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:104:14)
>       at next (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:104:14)
>       at next (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:104:14)
>       at next (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:104:14)
>       at next (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:104:14)
>       at next (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:104:14)
>       at next (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:104:14)
>       at next (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:104:14)
>       at next (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:104:14)
>       at next (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:104:14)
>       at next (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:104:14)
>       at next (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:104:14)
>       at Route.dispatch (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:91:3)
>       at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:82:5)
>       at C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:267:22
>       at Function.proto.process_params (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:321:12)
>       at next (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:261:10)
>       at methodOverride (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\method-override\index.js:79:5)
>       at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:82:5)
>       at trim_prefix (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:302:13)
>       at C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:270:7
>       at Function.proto.process_params (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:321:12)
>       at next (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:261:10)
>       at logger (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\morgan\index.js:136:5)
>       at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:82:5)
>       at trim_prefix (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:302:13)
>       at C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:270:7
>       at Function.proto.process_params (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:321:12)
>       at next (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:261:10)
>       at C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\body-parser\lib\read.js:111:5
>       at done (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\body-parser\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:248:14)
>       at IncomingMessage.onEnd (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\body-parser\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:294:7)
>       at IncomingMessage.g (events.js:199:16)
>       at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:104:17)
>       at _stream_readable.js:908:16
>       at process._tickDomainCallback (node.js:381:11)
>   info: [debug] Responding to client with error: {"status":33,"value":{"message":"A new session could not be created. (Original error: Requested a new session but one was in progress)","origValue":"Requested a new session but one was in progress"},"sessionId":"2c9eecab-c67b-45e0-b97f-0faa98dfd000"}
>   info: <-- POST /wd/hub/session 500 6.272 ms - 250 
>   info: [debug] Didn't get a new command in 60 secs, shutting down...
>   info: Shutting down appium session
>   info: [debug] Pressing the HOME button
>   info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Users\mwebster\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s emulator-5554 shell "input keyevent 3"
>   info: [debug] Stopping logcat capture
>   info: [debug] Logcat terminated with code null, signal SIGTERM
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got data from client: {"cmd":"shutdown"}
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got command of type SHUTDOWN
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Returning result: {"status":0,"value":"OK, shutting down"}
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Closed client connection
>   info: [debug] [UIAUTOMATOR STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: numtests=1
>   info: [debug] [UIAUTOMATOR STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: stream=.
>   info: [debug] [UIAUTOMATOR STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: id=UiAutomatorTestRunner
>   info: [debug] [UIAUTOMATOR STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: test=testRunServer
>   info: [debug] [UIAUTOMATOR STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: class=io.appium.android.bootstrap.Bootstrap
>   info: [debug] [UIAUTOMATOR STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: current=1
>   info: [debug] [UIAUTOMATOR STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS_CODE: 0
>   info: [debug] Sent shutdown command, waiting for UiAutomator to stop...
>   info: [debug] [UIAUTOMATOR STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: stream=
>   info: [debug] [UIAUTOMATOR STDOUT] Test results for WatcherResultPrinter=.
>   info: [debug] [UIAUTOMATOR STDOUT] Time: 61.482
>   info: [debug] [UIAUTOMATOR STDOUT] OK (1 test)
>   info: [debug] [UIAUTOMATOR STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS_CODE: -1
>   info: [debug] UiAutomator shut down normally
>   info: [debug] Cleaning up android objects
>   info: [debug] Cleaning up appium session
>   info: [debug] We shut down because no new commands came in

Comment: ^ Code formatting is probably better to show logs - that will preserve newlines and spacing, making it much easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

Appium internally uses UIAutomator to find elements. If you are executing your code using appium then your UIAutomator is already in use and if you try to use it manually then appium will loose the control of UIAutomator.

Comment: not sure I understand your response? I'm using 'Inspector' button and get this when clicking 'refresh' button when 'inspector' is launched?

Comment: Also I'm a 'newb' and have since learned that there are many problems with trying to use Appium's Inspector on an windows install? As a work-around I'm using sdk uiautomateviewer?